# Spring-boot jackson error on Maven with war file, but not jar file with com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jackson

I have a very weird problem with Spring-boot 1.5.2 build with Maven to war package which it has error with Jackson dependency, only on Ubuntu 16.04 as I'm using another Centos 7 and no problem with starting application as war or jar file.

After building with Maven to jar or war, I can run built package with

```
javar -jar target/project.war (or project.jar)
```

and Embedded Tomcat will start. Also the war package could be deployed to an external Tomcat in webapps directory of Centos 7. For Ubuntu 16.04, I could only run .jar file with Tomcat embedded but not war file with Tomcat Embedded/External.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:564)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:474)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:588)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.java:29)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.httpPutFormContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:142)
```

Here is the pom file https://pastebin.com/13MwTm89 which I only add another dependency from Jackson for deserializing XML to object.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

here is the full dependencies for Jackson

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep 'jackson' 
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.7:compile
```

Comment: Why do you use `jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0` and all the rest has 2.8.7?

Comment: It is not from me, it is from Spring-boot dependency parent.

Comment: Try to downgrade your version. Or exclude the spring's dependency and add yours with correct version

Comment: tried, but not help also don't you think it is very weird when a jar package can run but not war, also it is for only Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Check the war file to be sure correct versions are added. Check tomcat as well. Could be it has own wrong version jackson libs

Comment: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()` has been part of Jackson since 2.3 so you must have a very old version being loaded from somewhere on your Ubuntu system. I'd configure Tomcat to launch the JVM with `-verbose:class`. The output will tell you from where `JsonFactory` is being loaded.

Comment: Try also to change scope to be `provided` for all the jackson libs

Comment: @StanislavL: I tried your suggestion but it still has error. Also, I tried to build 1 war file in Centos 7 and 1 war file in Ubuntu 16.04 which is error. Two output files are the same size, no difference in any lib, class file as I extracted them to folders to compare. But, only the war in Centos 7 can run with java -jar package.war.

I don't know what is different here as all of of them are using embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Try to explicitly add the `jackson-annotations` dependency with version. I guess following happens. Tomcat has somewhere own version of the lib. You don't have the lib in your jar so tomcat loads own lib but version is not compatible with yours. If you set scope to `provided` (for all jackson libs) the tomcat will use own libraries which OR you provide all the libraries yourself to "suppress" tomcat's ones.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem after trying to comment out each dependency individually in pom.xml, it is due to a fasterxml from very old version in an internally project which is generated to jar file and I included in pom.xml of main project.

The internal project contains some dependencies and I think one of them contains this old jackson-core library, I think it is grpc or protobuf.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Somehow in Ubuntu 16.04, Maven 3.3.9 prefer this jackson-core instead of newest version from Spring boot or specified directly in pom.xml.

It does not happen when in Centos 7 with Maven 3.5.0 when it runs without problem with Jackson as it used the newest dependency.